TypeError: node.forEach is not a function in Dynamoose query with contains filter on array field
I’m facing an issue while querying DynamoDB using Dynamoose in a Node.js application. I’m trying to apply a filter to search for a specific value in an array field (cars), but I keep getting the error:
TypeError: node.forEach is not a function

Here’s the relevant part of the error:

2024-09-19 04:44:31 [error] [undefined] [undefined]: TypeError: node.forEach is not a function
 at eval (webpack://xyz-api/./node_modules/dynamoose/dist/Item.js?:283:22)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at traverse (webpack://xyz-api/./node_modules/dynamoose/dist/Item.js?:277:31)
    at eval (webpack://xyz-api/./node_modules/dynamoose/dist/Item.js?:294:17)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at traverse (webpack://xyz-api/./node_modules/dynamoose/dist/Item.js?:277:31)
    at Item.attributesWithSchema (webpack://xyz-api/./node_modules/dynamoose/dist/Item.js?:300:5)
    at eval (webpack://xyz-api/./node_modules/dynamoose/dist/Item.js?:466:43)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Item.objectFromSchema (webpack://xyz-api/./node_modules/dynamoose/dist/Item.js?:465:46)



I am trying to apply a filter to check if the cars array contains a specific value ("audi" in this case). The cars field is an array.


Here’s a dummy document structure I am working with:

{
  "GSI1PK": "COMP#123",
  "GSI1SK": "ID#456",
  "cars": ["audi", "bmw", "mercedes"],
  "companyDetails": {
    "name": "Test Company",
    "location": "New York"
  }
}

I am using Dynamoose to query a DynamoDB table with an array field. Here’s my function:
typescript
Copy code
async getAllComps(carsFilterOptions: CarsListingFilterOptions): Promise<QueryResponse<DbCompanyCarDto>> {

    // Query to fetch all cars
    let query = CompanyCarModel.query("GSI1PK")
        .eq(this.GSI1PK)
        .where("GSI1SK")
        .beginsWith("ID#");

    // Applying filter based on array field
    if (carFilterOptions.cars?.length) {
        global.logger.debug("Cars Filter Applied");
        query = query.and().where("cars").contains("audi");
    }

    // Execute the query and return the result
    return query.exec();
}

